# Xcode comment selection shortcut not working on European keyboard

Tags: xcode

I have an Apple keyboard (Norwegian) with numeric keypad and I can't get the Xcode shortcut for comment selection (cmd + /) to work. I have to change to Input source = US every time I want to comment out a block.  When I change from US to Norwegian input source the Xcode -> Editor -> Structure -> comment selection shortcut disappears.

Does anyone know why changing input source from Norwegian/Swedish/German (I guess all European languages) have this effect.  What is the "European" shortcut for comment selection ?

Are Europeans not allowed by Apple to comment select..!? ;-)

Any ideas would be much appreciated !

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fix this by going to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**, then **App Shortcuts**. Click the **+** button and select Xcode from the top drop bar. Then set the **Menu Title** to **Comment Selection**. Next select the keyboard shortcut box and press the desired keyboard combination, then click OK.

It seems that the Norwegian keyboard's encoding of the **/** character does not work in shortcuts, so you should use something else than the /

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately i tried this, and it does not work, nothing change.  Xcode -> Editor -> Structure -> comment selection shortcut is still blank

Comment: @karlml Make sure that **Comment Selection** is correctly spelled and capitalized. Then, restart Xcode. If it is blank, try using the shortcut anyway. If it doesn't work either, use a different key combination

Comment: Ok, this is very odd. If I changed to CMD + * it works... and I get cmd* in the menu  Why can I not use cmd+/ ? (I also had to add the same key combination for Uncomment Selection)

Comment: @karlml I think it is something to do with the encoding. Maybe the **/** is a different character on the Norwegian keyboard. There are 3 Norwegian keyboards with seemingly the same input. Try the PC one

Comment: Hmm, well it looks the same, and it types the same, and if I type // in Xcode with that button, the code is certainly commented out.  But maybe ISO standard have it recognised as something else, or apple have the keyboard mapped wrong, who knows.  Thanks

Comment: I guess you should change the answer to specify that you should add another shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me
 
For xcode 8 -> 
sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl 
 
restart your computer

Comment: not sure though if it wasn't just restarting computer that helped me; in my case "Editor -> Structure -> Comment Selection" was always disabled whether i had any code selectet or not

Comment: @igrek its possible as xcode is having a lot of problems and some times just restarting it fixes the issue. how ever in my case it never worked unless i executed this command..

Comment: ok, thanks, I had it reproduced couple more times and the command definitely works. No need to restart a computer, you only need to restart xcode

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Problem with the German keyboard. It works if I press shift+cmd+/. Probably because without the shift it's cmd+7 and the "/" is activated when you press shift.